# Showing messages Inbox of a gmail account

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to read emails in any gmail account. Here are the codes, how to list the Inbox items from any gmail account that has been foldered with getMail() method.

mailReader.java

```
package myMail.namespace;

import java.security.Security;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class mailReader extends javax.mail.Authenticator{

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new myMail.namespace.JSSEProvider());
    }

    static Session session;
    static Store store;

    public static Message [] getMail() throws MessagingException{
        connect();
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
        return messages;
        }

    private static void connect() throws MessagingException{
        if (null != session)
            return;
            java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");
            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "myMail@gmail.com", "myPass");
    }
}
```

And the readMail Class

```
package myMail.namespace;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class readMail extends ListActivity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Message[] messages = new Message[] { };

    try {
        messages = mailReader.getMail();
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        Log.e("mailReader getMail error. in readmail.java", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Message>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Message message = getItem(position);
            TextView resultView = null;
            resultView = new TextView(super.getContext());
            try {
                resultView.setText(message.getSubject());
            } 
            catch (MessagingException e) {
                Log.e("resultView.setText in readmail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return resultView;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

And JSSE Provider

```
package myMail.namespace;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the reason but ``if (null == convertView ||!(convertView instanceof TextView))`` leaves resultView null in case convertView is instance of TextView.

Comment: I'm curious how you expected us to go about debugging your NPE; just read the code and figure it out? Create a project, compile it, run it?

Comment: @harism, after removing state if (null == convertView ||!(convertView instanceof TextView)) it is working great. Thank you.

Comment: Another solution would've been to add else -clause, in which you cast convertView to resultView. Assuming it's ok to re-use convertView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the super.getView() in the function of "public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)" to get a valid layout view and find the text view from it, then fill with the subject of email.